# All data has gone

Tags: technology, adaptability

Something just happend to our universe: all data storage on our devices disappeared (mobile, computer, server, camera, pen drive, HD, CD, magnetic disk and any other device). Our physical networks are still working, but our logical networks don't work because all software was deleted with the data.
Books and all media in paper are still intact, as well as electricity. 
All the laws of physics are still the same too.

What happens with the human race? And how many times will we need to rebuild our digital knowledge? And how will it be rebuilt?

Comment: Welcome to the site FBA, the setup for this question is interesting but I think when you get to the question itself the concept is far too broad.  If you could narrow the question to what the impact of losing all data would be on X.  Then I think you have a good question.

Comment: Power generation and switching stations rely heavily on software, yet you say electricity is intact -- In what sense is electricity intact? All of the microprocessor systems have "data" embedded in the hardware as well as software in most cases. Does the hardware survive because it has a physical component, if so why are CDs wiped, the optical pits are physical. Why are mag disks wiped, the magnetic fields are physical.

Comment: Why will we need to rebuild more than once? If we don't know what's causing the problem, how can we protect our data from a future wiping likewise how could we predict how often it would occur without historical data or and understanding of why it happened.

Comment: I think this question is too broad.  Asking how much data is lost or how long it takes to refill is a simple question.  Asking 'what happens to the human race' is too large and open ended.  Perhaps it would be better to focus on more exact and answerable questions for your premise?

Comment: @dsollen Even "Asking how much data is lost or how long it takes to refill" is a simple question.

Comment: @dsollen Sorry, pressed enter too soon and didn't finish up correcting in time. Even "Asking how much data is lost or how long it takes to refill"  is a massively complicated question.  What exactly counts?  There really isn't a clear line between "data" and "device".  The data is just the state of the hardware, which can be fixed to varying degrees with a smooth continuum from the ephemeral movement of current though a circuit to gross structure of machines.  There is no easy, obvious point in between where you can easily say "this is data and that is device".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not try an answer....there's probably a few routes here.

Everything dependent on computer software fails.

- Power fails.  The electric grid might still exist, but the power stations are computer controlled (and I believe the distribution grid would fail as well, but I'm not fully sure)
- Banking and monetary systems fail.  There's much no longer kept in hard copy form these days
- All communication dies.  This includes internet, tv, phones (2 pair copper might still function?  unsure there)
- Our food distribution system fails.  Most warehousing, inventory, and distribution is computer controlled.  Losing power would also bring an end to refrigeration (I think automatically monitored temperatures are computer software controlled and would fail.  My personal fridge wouldn't work)
- Our water distribution/cleaning systems fail.  I believe most modern sewer systems and water reclamation systems are computer driven
- A good chunk of our farming is automated, from them automatically milking cow stations (and feeding?) to irrigation.  Our food supply chain would likely crumble.
- Oil pipelines fail and potentially burst.  Ya, we'd flood a few places with crude.  Refineries would also halt production
- Manufacturing dies, except for manual labor factories I guess.
- Air travel is no longer possible.
- Satellites are a write off and would need to be reestablished.  Astronauts on the ISS are also goners.
- New cars would fail to start.  Gas stations wouldn't be able to serve their gasoline either.
- Personally I'd be locked out of my building and a few other locations that I have key cards for
- Grocery shopping would be near impossible...everything from scanners/inventory control to check out till would be failing
- Nuclear plants would need immediate manual attention and we'd likely see either close calls or a few meltdowns.
- Short of deadbolts, most security systems are instant fails

I'm probably missing a few...but food, water, communication, power, distribution/inventory, monetary, and security...SHort answer is we likely don't recover without a decent period of anarchy and probably mass starvation and a pretty big die out.  We'll survive it, but not well.

Kinda funny that people clinging on to their worthless printed encyclopedia's would suddenly have possession of a good chunk of our collective knowledge.

Comment: Don't forget aircraft (fly-by-wire anyone?) and vehicles already in operation (electronic steering and ABS). There will be significant death toll in the first few minutes after this event happens.

Comment: Copper pairs might work, but the phone exchanges are just big computers.

Comment: @SJuan76 - thats what I expected, short of a dedicated copper line (at this point it might as well be tin cans with a string) no phone communication would exist.

Comment: All phone networks are going down hard. Though POTS may be used for the last mile, their is lots of automated swtiches etc. between the endpoints. Almost all cars have embedded chips these day. On the plus side, preppers have plenty of food, water and ammo socked away. On the minus, they are far outnumbered by the drones. Those remote tribes in Africa, etc. are sounding pretty attractive.